# Why does blender render a single image instead of the whole video?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render an animation, and every time I go to render, it only renders one frame and stops. Please help.  I am stuck until I can fix this.

Thanks

Comment: What else you have tried? Do you clicked only "render" or "render animation" button?

Comment: Yes, I clicked animation in the render panel

Comment: Sounds like a frame range issue.?

Comment: Could you further explain please?

Comment: Please check Dimensions > Frame Range in the Scene tab.

Comment: Could you post the .blend, it is hard to guess what of many things is incorrectly done.

Comment: I will try to post the .blend

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the .blend

Comment: you can upload it here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It is uploading now   it is uploading slowly

Comment: I can't post it because the file is 40,000 plus KB

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few things to check:

[image]

1. **The *animation* button** in the render panel (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>) is used for animation. The *render* button on the left (with a camera icon) will only render one frame.
2. **Frame step**. The default value is 1, meaning that it will render all of the frames in the specified range. Higher values will make the render/playbak skip frames. In any case it shouldn't be too high (it's too high in this screenshot, for example)
3. The **Start** and **End** frame determine the range of frames to be animated/rendered.

By the looks of your comments, these probably aren't your issue. However we might as well have them in an answer, since they're things that in general affect your symptoms.

Comment: Notice that I have commented before you. Please read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at.. If this isn't the solution for _you_, it might still be able to help other people. The question is vague enough that this answer definitely addresses it.