# Blender rendering only one frame, not whole animation

Tags: camera

I am trying to render a short animation. It plays as it should in the render preview, but when I render it the only thing displayed is a single  frame. I am not using multiple cameras (only one), and I have my only camera set  as the active camera. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: This is similar to another user's question but the answer provided was info I already had (it didn't work)

My render settings:
[image]

Link to .blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/0zva43sa2sdi9x2/Agassi2.blend

When rendering it won't follow the camera's view or path. It renders some other still image of a random area on the surface's grid. As mentioned above I don't have any additional cameras.

Comment: Are you rendering using the animation button (or Ctrl+F12)? Did you set a range of frames to be rendered? If not please edit your question and share some more information on how you set up your render settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does blender render a single image instead of the whole video?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19020/why-does-blender-render-a-single-image-instead-of-the-whole-video)

Comment: Possible, but not the case

Comment: can you upload your file?

Comment: @cegaton That much I can do.

Comment: Ive uploaded the .blend file

Comment: are you sure you're pressing the "Animate" button, and not the "Render" button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of objects disabled for rendering:

[image]

Then you have no output file or format:

[image]

Once you set your output you can render with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The thing that jumps out at me is your Frame Step is 236.  That means it will try to render frame 1, then it will increment to 1+236, and since 237 is after the end, there is no more work to do.  It is unusual to use a Frame Step other than 1.

Answer (score 4):

> but when I render it the only thing displayed is a single in-animate frame.

I don't know what front you mean exactly by this, but your uploaded file suggests several courses of investigation:

1. None of the objects are currently set to render.  Make sure that is indeed what you want, by making sure the things you want to render has that camera next to it on the Outliner.
2. I don't know if this is some sort of cross-computer transfer error (like all the textures missing), but you don't have a output file type defined.  Trying to render the scene gave me no output files.  Just go under Output under Render settings, and choose something.