# Blender rendering just one frame when percentage scale is >50% (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I have a scene where I just move the camera on a path.
It lasts 96 frames but when I try to render the animation with 100% percentage scale it stops at the first frame as it is a single image.
I've tried changing it at 50% and in that case it works and I have as output the correctly animated video.
I've also tried to render all the 96 single frames as images and then put them in the video sequence editor to create the final video, but it didn't work: it still renders just the first frame and then it stops.

These are my settings:
[image]

Edit:
This is the blender file (just the camera and the path with the cube). I don't know why but by appending camera and path in a this new file, the camera moves just a bit along the path (while if I add the entire scene it works)
[image]

Comment: Try to disable compositing and sequencer from the post processing and render again.and see if that works.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19020/why-does-blender-render-a-single-image-instead-of-the-whole-video http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38445/blender-rendering-only-one-frame-not-whole-animation

Comment: I saw that question before posting this and the settings I had (and that are in the image) are ok. I also tried by deleting unnecessary objects but the problem remains.

Comment: Do you click "render" or "animation" button?

Comment: can you upload your file? You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the link on your question.

Comment: @parameciostudio I clicked "animation".

Comment: @cegaton the file is too big, is there another way to upload it?

Comment: What happens if you render as an image sequence?

Comment: @cegaton the same, it renders the first frame and then it stops

Comment: Do you have anything on the VSE? If you do unclick the **Sequencer** button on the **Post Processing** panel. see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering/5286#5286

Comment: could you upload the file with only the camera and the path and a cube?

Comment: it might help if you could post the render, just to analyze the scene.

Comment: @cegaton I didn'thave anything... anyway I tried it but the result is the same :\ now I'll try to post the file just with the camera and the path

Comment: It seems that you missed to append the path. Here's the console wanring: Read library:  '/Users/lorenzo/Downloads/TreeWithWallPond.blend', '//TreeWithWallPond.blend', parent '<direct>'
Unable to open '/Users/lorenzo/Downloads/TreeWithWallPond.blend': No such file or directory
Cannot find lib '/Users/lorenzo/Downloads/TreeWithWallPond.blend'
LIB ERROR: Curve: 'NurbsPath' unread lib block missing from '/Users/lorenzo/Downloads/TreeWithWallPond.blend', parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the animation works at 50%, you could try doubling the resolution and rendering at 50%.

Maybe the .blend file has some issue.

**First you could append the scene to a new file.**

If the animation doesn't work yet, you could start from a new file with the default cube and light, and append only camera and path.

Add the other objects until the animation stop at the first frame and check the very last object you've added.